# Understand Ansible condition based on boolean with the "is" syntax

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to understand the logic of the syntax for condition based on boolean in ansible tasks.

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: stat module
      stat:
        path: playbook.yml
      register: output_stat

#DEBUG      
    - debug:
        var: output_stat.changed

    - debug:
        var: output_stat.stat.exists

#CONDITION
    - name: debug condition on output_stat is changed
      debug:
        msg: "output_stat is changed"
      when: output_stat is changed

    - name: debug condition on output_stat.stat is exists
      debug:
        msg: "file exists"
      when: output_stat.stat is exists
```

Running the playbook with `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` give following console output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [stat module] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 April 2022  11:48:10 +0200 (0:00:00.022)       0:00:00.022 ******** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 April 2022  11:48:10 +0200 (0:00:00.385)       0:00:00.408 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output_stat.changed": false
}

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 April 2022  11:48:10 +0200 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:00.445 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output_stat.stat.exists": true
}

TASK [debug condition on output_stat is changed] *************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 April 2022  11:48:10 +0200 (0:00:00.036)       0:00:00.482 ******** 
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug condition on output_stat.stat is exists] *********************************************************************************************************
Thursday 14 April 2022  11:48:10 +0200 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:00.520 ******** 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output_stat.stat is exists' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if output_stat.stat is exists %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found\n\nThe error appears to be in '/tmp/test/playbook.yml': line 23, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: debug condition on output_stat.stat is exists\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Why is the first condition "output_stat is changed" working, but not the second "output_stat.stat is exists". I don't understand as they both refer to boolean values.

I understand that I could use

```yaml
    - name: debug condition on output_stat is changed
      debug:
        msg: "output_stat is changed"
      when: output_stat.changed

    - name: debug condition on output_stat.stat is exists
      debug:
        msg: "file exists"
      when: output_stat.stat.exists
```

instead to make it work, so I'm not looking for a solution. I'm really wondering how the "is failed" is not giving any error and the "is exists" does... Is that related to a very specific ansible behavior ?

Comment: Because `exists` is not part of the addon Jinja tests Ansible is providing: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results

Comment: And in opposition, the [`changed`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f68c66a3ef2390d21f5eeb10bb6b151058570206/lib/ansible/plugins/test/core.py#L62) test is something that does exists.

Answer (score 1):

`is changed` is a Jinja2 test provided by Ansible: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results

It's [implementation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f68c66a3ef2390d21f5eeb10bb6b151058570206/lib/ansible/plugins/test/core.py#L62) is a bit more advanced than just testing the boolean value of the field `changed` that is present on every result.

This test is a more convenient way to check if a task is in the changed state.

---

On the other hand, `exists` is just a simple field of the field `stat` in the result of a task `stat`. This field is a boolean as documented in the [module doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/exists).

This field can only be tested directly as a boolean.